# regular expression for # tags

Tags: java, regex

Using regular expression for identifying #tags

```
Like How are you #friends #today is #great day.
```

Condition should be 
`#` should be starting of word.
it contains letters,digits and `-` .

`-`should not appear just after the #.
after and before `-` there should be character or digit.

A string can contain multiple tags.

How to write regular expression for itentifying above #tags.

I tried this `#{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+-*[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
#[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\b
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use this,

```
#[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

or

```
"(?<!\\S)#[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(?=\\s|$)"
```

or

```
"(?<!\\S)#[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\\b"
```

Comment: Thankyou for giving a different ways

Comment: Yes # should be starting of word

Comment: No it should not match. but both answers are matching foo#bar and considering #bar as tag

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with the `Alnum` class, validating as follows:

Starts with `#`, then at least one alphanumeric

Contains alphanumerics and hyphens

Hyphens must be surrounded by alphanumerics

```
//                | one "#"
//                || at least one alnum
//                ||           | alnums...| or...
//                ||           |          | | not preceded by hyphen
//                ||           |          | |    | hyphen
//                ||           |          | |    | | not followed by hyphen or end
//                ||           |          | |    | |       | 0 or more times
//                ||           |          | |    | |       | 
String pattern = "#\\p{Alnum}+(\\p{Alnum}|(?<!-)-(?!-|$))*";
String[] good = {
"#foo",
"#123",
"#foo-123"
};
String[] bad = {
    "foo",
    "123",
    "#foo-",
    "#foo--123"
};
for (String s: good) {
    System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));
}
for (String s: bad) {
    System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));
}
```

**Output**

```
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
```